# PageSpeed google Enable Compression often changing

Tags: asp.net, compression, pagespeed

I'm working on an ASP.NET webforms and I put this code in my web.config :

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
<scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
<dynamicTypes>
  <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
</dynamicTypes>
<staticTypes>
  <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
  <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true"/>     
  <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
</staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
```

Sometimes Google Page Speed Insights and PageSpeed extension on Chrome don't say the same message about enable compression. Sometimes there are about 10 files so it's high importance, sometimes it's just 4 files, so medium importance... Sometimes Mobile version shows 10 files while computer version shows 4. It seems to be random. For instance. I analyse at 11:00 it's not the same at 11:30 and not the same at 13:00... Can change everytime without data or code changes.

Can someone explain this strange thing ?

By the way, I don't know why among the 4 remaining files, there are still a css file and a js file not "enabled" since other css and js files are not in the list anymore.

I also would like to remove the WebResource.axd?d=...&t=... from the 4 remaining files on some pages. That's why I added a mimeType x-javascript. But it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

here what you should do:
1. Enable dynamic compression in IIS7 [enable compression](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingDynamicCompressionGzipDeflateForWCFDataFeedsODataAndOtherCustomServicesInIIS7.aspx)
2. Enable page compression by using this code:

```
public static bool IsGZipSupported()
{
  string AcceptEncoding = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[«Accept-Encoding»];
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AcceptEncoding) &&
     (AcceptEncoding.Contains(«gzip») || AcceptEncoding.Contains(«deflate»)))
    return true;
  return false;
}

public static void GZipEncodePage()
{
  if (IsGZipSupported())
  {
    HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    string AcceptEncoding = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers[«Accept-Encoding»];
    if (AcceptEncoding.Contains(«gzip»))
    {
      Response.Filter = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(Response.Filter,
                   System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
      Response.AppendHeader(«Content-Encoding», «gzip»);
    }
    else
    {
      Response.Filter = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(Response.Filter,
                   System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
      Response.AppendHeader(«Content-Encoding», «deflate»);
    }
  }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
HtmlUtil.GZipEncodePage();
}
```

3. Enable static content [enable static content](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent)